# How to get reverse color for menu buttons?

Tags: android

I have tried to create a menu connected to menu button with Android SDK.
As a result i have this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nWznrMT.png]

But what i want it wasnt this. I like to have something like this totaly reverse of first picture.
[image]

**Android manifest xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tunghuynh.comparotel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name0"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:name="com.tunghuynh.comparotel.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.tunghuynh.comparotel.AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the res/values/styles.xml

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
            <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
            <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
            <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
            <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
        </style>

        <style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
            <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
        </style>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
<!--        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item> -->
<!--         <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item> -->
<!--         <item name="android:textColor">@color/message_box_text</item> -->
        <!-- <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/menu_full_bg</item> -->
        <!-- <item name="android:foreground">#000000</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
        <drawable name="menu_full_bg">#8a8a8a</drawable>

    </resources>
```

Comment: Change the theme in you manifest.

Comment: whichpart i need to change

Comment: how iiwll doi do not know

Answer (score 0):

Changing theme to any light theme will give you a menu like this, to do this go and edit your manifest file, for setting theme for application wide specify theme parameter under  tag or for a particular activity, specify under desired  tag